# Android preferences from settings menu - for phonegap developer

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I've never written any single line in Java and I doesn't know much about the Java world, so when I hear that I can create android apps using phonegap I was very happy. But as I discovered later, I cannot escape from Java if I want to do something more.

I want to create settings page for my application, I found [phongeap extension](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/06/phongap-android-application-preferences.html) that allows me to read the phonegap applications settings but to use it I must create the settings GUI which can be done via XML and some Java. I found good [tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html) to do it but since I'm not Java developer I cannot understand much from it.

Can someone tell me where to put all this Java and XML stuff to simply get the settings GUI working in phonegap application. I mean what files I need, with what content and in what directories.

Comment: What part of my instructions confuses you?

Comment: You're tutorial was clear for me but when it come to creating preferences gui using Java and XML(as mention in the tutorial that I've posted in my post) I get confused.

Comment: Just read up on this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Comment: Simon, your plugin works for me, and would seem to solve this OP's problem, but I find that backing out of the preferences screen with the back button once its loaded up (using your show method) leads to the application crashing.  Any ideas?  Actually, I'll add a question on this.

Answer (score 0):

With phonegap you can escape all the java codes, as you'll see in the following code, you wont need any java code:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
>                       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <title>Cordova Menu Button Example</title>
>
>     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
>     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
>
>     // Call onDeviceReady when Cordova is loaded.
>     // At this point, the document has loaded but cordova-2.3.0.js has not.
>     // When Cordova is loaded and talking with the native device,
>     // it will call the event `deviceready`.
>     function onLoad() {
>         document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
>     }
>
>     // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
>     function onDeviceReady() {
>         // Register the event listener
>         document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
>     }
>
>     // Handle the menu button
>     function onMenuKeyDown() { alert("menu btn pressed");
>
>     }
>
>     </script>
>   </head>
>   <body onload="onLoad()">
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Dont use plugins for this feature, just go to the main [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events).
Also you may find the other events like:

- deviceready
- pause
- resume
- online
- offline
- backbutton
- batterycritical
- batterylow
- batterystatus
- menubutton
- searchbutton
- startcallbutton
- endcallbutton
- volumedownbutton
- volumeupbutton

Comment: FYI - menubutton event is supported only for Android and BlackBerry. So it does not truly multi-platform solution.